# Possible reason of "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ecommerce' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am running this code where script method is called once document is ready. Also, I can get the object if I put a debugger and alert its value but it throws an error saying
`"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ecommerce' of undefined"` while running locally.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsonObj = {
        "input": {
            "ecommerce": 
                {
                    "id": 123,
                    "name": "isEcommerce",
                    "type": "boolean",
                    "actionType" : "radioButton",
                    "child": {"yes":["p","q","e","w"],
                                "no":["a","b","c","d"]}
                },
            "bad website": 
            {
                "id": 2324,
                "name": "isBadWebsite",
                "type": "boolean",
                "actionType" : "radioButton",
                "child": {"yes":["erw","sd","sd","sd"],
                            "no":["sd","sd","sd","fd"]}
            }
        }
};
var data = jsonObj;     
$(document).ready(function(data){
    alert("HI!!");
    alert(data);
    alert(data.input);
    alert(data.input.ecommerce);
});

function tackleEvent(obj){
    alert("Clicked " + obj);

}
</script>
</head>
<title>Hello!</title>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

ERROR trace:

```
   Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'ecommerce' of undefined ui:34
    (anonymous function) ui:34
    f.Callbacks.n jquery.min.js:2
    f.Callbacks.o.fireWith jquery.min.js:2
    e.extend.ready jquery.min.js:2
    c.addEventListener.B jquery.min.js:2
```

Why is it not able to get the object and is working while typing same?

Comment: what does these 2 alert: 1) `alert(data);` and 2) `alert(data.input);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you noticed on the previous 2 alert boxes, the value shown for `data` would be:

```
function(a,b) { return new e.fn.init(a,b,h) }
```

which is because [an alias of jQuery namespace](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) has been passed inside the following function (with a local copy named `data`):

```
function(data){
    alert("HI!!");
    alert(data);
    alert(data.input);
    alert(data.input.ecommerce);
}
```

and has been named data. Thus, inside the above function; you can use:

```
data.ajax()
data.ready() //another
data.load()
// and all other jQuery functions.
```

To access global variable `data`; you'd need to use: `window.data`.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking a local variable, instead of the global variable.

When you call `$(document).ready(function(data){`, you are probably assuming that `data` in that function is the global variable `data`. What you are actually doing is creating a local variable, which contains whatever `$(document).ready( ... )` puts in it. As far as I know, the first variable in a function called by `$(document).ready( ... )` will contain `jQuery`.

You can fix it by removing `data` from that function call. It now uses the global variable instead.

```
$(document).ready( function(){
    alert("HI!!");
    alert(data);
    alert(data.input);
    alert(data.input.ecommerce);
});
```

Comment: Had there been an option, I would have selected two best answers! :)